# plotOptions.series.point.events returns null point data when using a drilldown

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm binding a click event on every series point in order to get the data associated with the point.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                       console.log("that > ", this);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I have a chart with no drilldown It works fine ( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ho4wewo/) ).

However, if I define a drilldown ( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97nma53g/) ) i can only get the point data for the inner series. The point data is null for the slice i just clicked to drilldown.

```
this > c {series: null, name: null, y: null, drilldown: null, options: null…}
```

Is this a bug or am i missing something ?

Comment: It looks like arguments[0] is populated even when this isn't.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird yes, but that's the event, arguments[0].point is still null.

Comment: You're right.  I saw x & y values and thought they were the point information. :)

Comment: I think you are intended to use `chart.events.drilldown` to get this info.

Comment: @Ondkloss seems you're right, i can access the e.seriesOptions.data[] from the event callback of chart.events.drilldown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug.

Reported to our developers [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3383).

Comment: No problem, glad i could help. I'll use another approach until this is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your click handler gets executed when the clicked element has already disappeared. Looks like a bug to me.

A quick fix would be to modify highcharts js/modules/drilldown.src.js around line 513 to look like this:

```
// Add the click event to the point label
H.addEvent(point, 'click', function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        point.doDrilldown();
    }, 100);
});
```

Here's a modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aauxLdnn).

Comment: It's a solution, but i'd prefer not to hack the library specially because it has to be updated.